# Error while adding new item to MongoDB array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add a new item to Treatment array.It's basically to store the list of procedures offered by a particular hospital.Hospital id is a unique id for a hospital and its created by a post api along with the list of treatments offered by that hospital.Later when hospital introduce a new surgical procedure,i need to add that into the treatment array,for that i have created a put API

I am getting the following error whenever I call the below snippet in API

```
The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: Treatment.$.procedureid
```

Please help me to resolve it.

You can find the model and controller code below:

#### Schema definition

```
var hospitalDoctorSchema = new Schema({
    hospitalID: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true, dropDups: true, default: 10000 },   
    Treatment: [{        
        procedureid: { type: Number},
        departmentId: { type: Number},
                name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
                costUpperBound: { type: Number, required: true },
                costLowerBound: { type: Number, required: true },                   
                departmentName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true},


    }],
    updated_at: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
});
```

#### Controller code to add new item to treatment array:

```
 hospitalModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "hospitalID": 10000}, { "$set": {"Treatment.$.procedureid"=1100}, { returnOriginal: false, upsert: true }, function (err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        logger.error("Error while updating record : - " + err.message);
        return res.status(500).json({ "Message": err.message });
    } else if (doc === null) {
        logger.error("Error while updating record : - Hospital not found in database");
        return res.status(408).json({ "Message": "Hospital not found in database" });
    }   

    res.status(200).json({ "Message": "Hopsital details for " + hospitalName + " have been updated successfully" });
});
```

Comment: `{ "$set": {"Treatment.$.procedureid"=1100}` is not a valid object.

Comment: You need to actually "match" something in the array before you can apply the positional `$` operator, so aside from the syntax error it would actually still throw an error even with the match condition. Typically you would "query" for something like the `"procedureid"` as a unique property and then apply the positional updates to the matching item properties. So it's not really clear in your question if your intent is to "update" or instead "append" to the array in question.

Comment: Neil,Sorry for not giving enough information in the question.I am trying to add a new item to Treatment array.It's basically to store the list of procedures offered by a particular hospital.Hospital id is a unique id for a hospital and its created by a post api along with the list of treatments offered by that hospital.Later when hospital introduce a new surgical procedure,i need to add that into the treatment array,for that i have created a put API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a new element in array. You have to use **$push** instead of **$set**. Because *$push* which is used to insert element and *$set* which used only for updation.
So

```
hospitalModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "hospitalID": 10000},{"$push": 
{"Treatment" : { "procedureid" : 1100 } } }, { returnOriginal: false, 
upsert: true }, function (err, doc) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add a new element to the array then you can use the [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator like the following:

```
hospitalModel.findOneAndUpdate({ "hospitalID": 10000}, 
{ "$push": {"Treatment" : { "procedureid" : 1100 } } }, 
{ returnOriginal: false, upsert: true }, function (err, doc) { ... });
```